# OpenCV - first frame covers second frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I am trying to take 2 photos, but as result I see first one two times. I have tried using two variables for frames and saving them as file. How can I fix the problem?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cv2
import time


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(0.25)
ret1, t1 = cap.read()
print 'ret1:', ret1
cv2.imshow('test',t1)

cv2.waitKey(0)

ret1, t1 = cap.read()
print 'ret1:', ret1
cv2.imshow('test1',t1)
cap.release()


while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```